# Breeze JS : Entity Errors preventing patch-up on the client

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I my client application I am calling entityManager.saveChanges to send all currently changed entities from the client up to the server. Then in the BeforeSaveEntity event on the server I am performing some server side validation on each entity to see if it should be excluded from the save map. So for example, my entity may have a value for description that is too long. So I return false from BeforeSaveEntity, and generate a new EntityError which will then be added to the saveResult.EntityErrors collection. All of the valid records that haven't been excluded from the save map then save off successfully, and my saveResult is returned to the client. But because of this single entity error, the auto-patchup of the entities returned does not occur back on the client. I looked at the source and basically there seems to be a check that says if there is anything in the saveResult.EntityErrors collection, don't bother with the patch-up. But There was only 1 entity that purposefully wasn't saved, so I still want to be able to patch up the others. Is this behavior by design? I want to be able to exclude certain entities from the save (which I can do using the BeforeSaveEntity event), but there doesn't seem to be any way of then getting the entity errors back to the client using the inbuilt mechanism, without the full patch-up being abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Saves in breeze are transactional if at all possible ( some backend providers, like MongoDb are not because they don't support it.).  This means that if any failures are experienced with any entities within a save bundle the entire save is reverted and an error is returned to the client.  This is by design.